# How to solve the error on this code?SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error

my English is not very good,so if I couldn't explain the question clearly,please forgive me.
I downloaded the Geany directly and used it without any setting(because there are always something wrong and I can't solve the problem.
I input code in geany，then copy and paste the in the python.
then……

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not again... do not post **images** of code, post **code** itself...

Answer (score 1):

Lines in the interpreter run one at a time.
Write a command, press Enter to execute it, and then write the next.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are posting the two instructions at once instead the firs instruction (the assignment) and the the second one (the print) but I'm not sure how you can do this. I'd suggest putting them copying and pasting first one, then the other.